# click to copy without copy button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");

  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copied: " + copyText.value;
}

function outFunc() {
  var tooltip = document.getElementById("myTooltip");
  tooltip.innerHTML = "Copy to clipboard";
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 140px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 150%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">

<div class="tooltip">
<button onclick="myFunction()" onmouseout="outFunc()">
  <span class="tooltiptext" id="myTooltip">Copy to clipboard</span>
  Copy text
  </button>
</div>
```

This is an example with copy button. 
I want to remove the copy button, click on the text and copy without copy button, to be clearer I want to add Emoji, so click on Emoji and copy without copy button. example: `<input type="text" value="" id="myInput">` how i can make this? Thanks

Comment: its javascript !you want naswer in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply bind click event to certain selector for where you want to copy. Here I have binded click event to input.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput" onclick="myFunction()">
```

Comment: thanks for your help, can you tall me, how to set that in CSS height: 30px;
    width: 30px; ?

Comment: @marko with jquery $('.class').height(100) $('.class').width(100)

Comment: Thank You. @5740382